# How to detect language of document containing multiple languages?

Tags: language-detection

I have documents which might contain multiple languages and might be in pdf or docx format , i want to detect language(whichever language's score is higher) of that document . I tried using TIKA library but it did not work properly if document contains more than one language.  IS there any API or library that i can use ?

Comment: It is a bit off-topic here, since your question don't have any [MRE]. You might ask on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ and you should consider [N-gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) based approaches and read entire textbooks on [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) or follow some university courses on that subject. You'll need several months of full-time work.

Comment: You also need to dive into the details of [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) and [OOXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) and study carefully both specifications. Software recommendations are **off-topic** here, ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually, "several months of work" is optimistic. It may be *several years of full time work*. Google employs teams of dozens of PhD-level computer scientists to code the same, and their source code base is rumored to have millions of source code lines. You could find costly proprietary software or web services doing what you need. Consider collaboration with NLP academics in India or abroad. I happen to know several of them in Europe.

Comment: For example, https://www.decoder-project.eu/ (I am on the photo)